# Firstore data is not function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore

I am not able to pull data on collection, getting this error

> Uncaught TypeError: doc.data is not a function

```
var db = firebase.firestore();
const docRef = db.collection("Slides");

getRealData = function() {
  docRef.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
    const myData = doc.data();
    console.log(myData);
  });
};

getRealData();
```

I find the solution if I pass fix id then below code work
(Although ID are random generate by firestore)

```
db.collection("Slides").doc("GYUzWG6jcOPob725wbnF")
.onSnapshot(function(doc) {
    console.log("Current data: ", doc.data());
});
```

**Firestore**
[image]

Answer (score 5):

In your first code sample, you're assuming that the snapshot callback attached to this:

```
db.collection("Slides")
```

Is similar to the one attached to this:

```
db.collection("Slides").doc("GYUzWG6jcOPob725wbnF")
```

In fact, they are not the same at all.

The first one will query for ALL the documents in the named collection, and it will give you a [QuerySnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QuerySnapshot) object in the callback.  This object does not have a data() method, and you need to iterate it to get all the document snapshots.

The second one will query for only the named document in the named collection, and you will get a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot) object back.

Since you didn't say what you're trying to accomplish, I can't recommend what you should be doing.  All I can say is that the two code bits you've shown are not at all alike, and you'd expect them to behave differently.

Comment: I know these are 2 different thing, I am trying to get all the documents under `Slides` Collections, its not working. BUT, once I pass `ID` it fetch the data. I need all the data under `Slides`

Comment: Please read my answer again, and click through to the API documentation.  If you get a QuerySnapshot from the first sample, then use the documented API to iterate the documents in the results.  If you're having a problem with that, then ask a specific question about what the problem is.  Right now your question is just asking "why do these things work differently".

Answer (score 0):

By the error message looks like data is not a function, it mean that you don't have to use parentheses when assigning it to variable, so change your assignment to this line:
`const myData = doc.data;`

Comment: its return me function with this code `const myData = doc.data;`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, my approach was wrong, use `get` function to get all the data.

```
docRef.get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
        console.log(doc.id, " => ", doc.data());
    });
});
```

Comment: I think you don't understand how getting data works with Firestore... get() will not listen for data changes, and you can actually do the same thing wiht the onSnapshot() function, you juste have to loop through the array of objects you get back. Please have a look at this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data

Comment: @Firebaser, I agree with you, I tried `var docRef = db.collection("cities").doc("SF");` my Data `Collection` have around 20+ dynamic `ID's`. so I need to all documents in a collection.